# The Music Grunniens V2

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, music

[image: The Music Grunniens V2.0]

Clues: [music notes]

Instructions: Name That Actor

_ _ _ _ _ _ C _ _ _ _

Comment: On the other hand, it's not exactly clear whether changing those notes would materially change the answer - i.e. whether this is a new puzzle or a new version of the same puzzle. Tyler, please could you clarify?

Comment: It's the same answer with a slight change to the question. Didn't know if anyone would remember the previous one. Wanted to see which would get a better score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actor in this riddle is:

> Huge Yakman = Hugh Jackman

This is similar to another riddle that was asked a while back. Consider the notes present on the staff, and how they are separated into sets.

> Two Ds -> D + D = 4 + 4 = 8 = H 
>  Three Gs -> G + G + G = 7 + 7 + 7 = 21 = U 
>  One G -> G = 7 = G 
>  One E -> E = 5 = E 
>  Five Es -> E + E + E + E + E = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 25 = Y 
>  One A -> A = 1 = A 
>  One A, Two Es -> A + E + E = 1 + 5 + 5 = 11 = K 
>  One A, Two Fs -> A + F + F = 1 + 6 + 6 = 13 = M 
>  One A -> A = 1 = A 
>  Seven Bs -> B + B + B + B + B + B + B = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 14 = N

You can likely see how this spelling sounds like the actor's name.